# Visual Studio 2008/2010 addin - errors list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, envdte

Hello fellow developers!

I am trying to get the build error codes from a visual studio add-in.

I found a way to get errors from the Error List window, with this code:

```
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("View.ErrorList", " ");
myErrors = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.ErrorList;
```

But this only gives me the errors currently displayed in the errors list, so if no warnings are selected, they will not show up. But the bigger issue with this is that I only get a description of the error, and not the error code itself. So I'm afraid that if i'll search for a specific error string I will run into language-specific issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by parsing the build output. The build output does contain the error codes.

More about this in my blog - [yogiprogi](http://yogiprogi.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/getting-build-errors-from-visual-studio-2010-extension/)